# How to add special characters in kendo grid custom command text(i.e VIew/Edit)

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.AnalysisRequests).Name("Team").Columns(columns =>
{columns.Bound(i => i.Text4);columns.Bound(i => i.Text5);columns.Command(commands => commands.Custom("View/Edit").Click("EditRequest")).Width(130);});
```

This is displaying Button Name as "View Edit",when you click on it,this will opens a popup.When I changed the button text as "View/Edit",It will not opens the Popup.when click on the button it displaying error "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a.k-grid-View/Edit".If there is any solution please let me know.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: columns.Command(commands => commands.Custom("custom").Click("EditAnalysisRequest").Text("View/Edit")).Width(130);                                                         we can add special characters like this

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
columns.Command(commands =>
                      {
                          commands.Edit().Text(" ")
                              .UpdateText("updateButtonText")
                              .CancelText("cancelButtonText"); // The "edit" command will edit and update data items
                          commands.Custom("Delete").Text(" ").Click("DeleteStuff"); // The "destroy" command removes data items
                      }).Width(95);
```